# React Router - trigger file download

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

How to skip the react routing in case of file paths? It seems react router intercepts all links. Example below - the hardcoded link `/1.pdf` seems to trigger the router.

How do we trigger file downloads?

```
const Main = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>React Router Playground</h1>
            <Link to="/download">Download Area</Link>
        </div>
    );
};

const Download = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Download Area</h1>
            <a href="/1.pdf">Download</a>
        </div>
    );
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
                    <Route path="/download" component={Download} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

This is a rather simple example so the hardcoded link. These are dynamic and passed as props in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

The following code combined with a `NoMatch` component should work, reloading the URL if it's a valid resource.

```js
<Router>
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
      <Route exact path="/download" component={Download} />
      <Route component={NoMatch} />
      <Route onEnter={() => window.location.reload()} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Comment: Can you share `NoMatch` component code? Is it same as here - https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match. Won't a `onEnter` trigger a reload every time route changes?